# Oracle: Is there a way to encode a value using the unix crypt method?

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, plsql, crypt

Is there a way to encode a value using the [unix crypt method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29) in oracle 10g?

(Other DBMS like [MySQL support this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/encryption-functions.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you are one Oracle8i or higher this is possible.

The solution is to write a Java Stored Procedure which can execute OS commands, and use that to run Unix `crypt`.  Tim Hall's Oracle-Base site has an example of how to code one of these things.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/ShellCommandsFromPLSQL.php).

Comment: Hope he's not on windows; if so, he's going to have to install POSIX to boot.

Comment: I'm not on windows, but unfortunately this is not an option for me. anyway, i'll accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `DBMS_CRYPTO` PL/SQL package has encryption, but none using the native weakness of the Unix `crypt(1)`.  It's much more analogous to `crypt(3)`.

If you need the exact `crypt(1)` implementation, you're going to have to code it yourself.  Here's the [C code](http://google.com/codesearch/p#118goTAkg2o/usr/src/cmd/crypt.c) for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the exact crypt encoding.